# When authenticating user in adLDAP the result is "User authentication unsuccessful"

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory

**INFO:** I am trying to authenticate and adLDAP

**PROBLEM:** adLDAP telling me "User authentication unsuccessful"

**QUESTION:** How do I find out what I need to do when there are no errors telling me what handle this.

**SEARCHED/TRIED:**

1. http://adldap.sourceforge.net/faq.php
2. stackoverflow.com/questions/2465260/using-adldap-php-class-but-getting-error-when-looking-for-group-user-belongs-to
3. adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_examples#authenticating_a_user
4. http://phreek.org/blog/2011/12/enable-php-ldap-module-in-xampp

**CODE:**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/adLDAP.php');
$adldap = new adLDAP();

$username = "user";
// $username = "domain\user"; // I have also tried
$password = "pass";

$authUser = $adldap->authenticate($username, $password);
if ($authUser == true) {
  echo "User authenticated successfully";
}
else {
  echo "User authentication unsuccessful";
}

echo('<hr />');

$result=$adldap->user_info("jboyle");
print_r($result);
```

**HTML OUTPUT:**

```
User authentication unsuccessful

Fatal error: Call to undefined method adLDAP::user_info() in C:\xampp\htdocs\adLDAP\compare.php on line 18
```

Comment: It is not adLDAP that tells you "User authentication unsuccessful", it's your code. To check what adLDAP can tell you run `$adldap->get_last_error();`

Comment: I could see were you would think that, I think I found a few things out this weekend. I will post a an answer very soon. To be more specific "$adldap->authenticate" is returning a false and I do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace:**

```
echo "User authentication unsuccessful";
```

with

```
echo "Username '{$username}' login failed: ".$adldap->getLastError();
```

**Result:**

```
Username 'user' login failed: Can't contact LDAP server
```

**Info/sources:**

https://sourceforge.net/projects/adldap/forums/forum/358759/topic/1719128?message=4368835
http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=ldap_over_ssl#tell_apache_how_to_use_ldaps

Do a phpinfo() and check where the HOME variable points to in the Apache environment. Create a symbolic link or copy ldap.conf to this location.

If you get a connect error may be because your local OpenSSL installation doesn't recognise the certificate (or its authority) provided by the server. This can be circumvented by adding the following line to ldap.conf on your server or similar:

Change TLS_REQCERT allow to TLS_REQCERT never

Apache must be able to read ldap.conf, you cannot skip this step.